# Longest code to reduce words

Tags: date, code-bowling

Write a code in your favorite language which reduces words To **`first three characters`**.

```
Input  : One word  
Output : First three letters
```

For example

```
INPUT  : ProGramming
OUTPUT : Pro

INPUT  : puZZles
OUTPUT : puZ

INPUT  : BoWling
OUTPUT : BoW
```

**`Output needs to be case sensitive`**

**Rule-1**
All statements should be meaningful and useful.
For example
the C++ snippet below surely increases the score but is unnecessary.
**`The similar code snippets below is banned.`**

```
std::cout<<"abcabc";
std::cout<<"\b\b\b\b\b\b";
```

**Rule-2**
Do not use infinite add-subtract or multiplication-division (or any other kind of) infinite progressions to increase the score.
For example
**`The similar code snippets below is banned.`**

```
if(strcmp(str,"monday")==0)  //The function strcmp() returns 0 if both
                             //strings are same (including NULL character)
cout<<110+1-1+1-1+1-1....inf //110 is ASCII value of 'm'
```

**Winner**
Winner will be chosen on the basis of score (Most score wins) after 4 days from now.
If there is a tie then the one who submitted the answer first is the winner

Comment: Also, `ThRUsday -> ThRU`: Are you stripping the last *four* characters there?

Comment: @m.buettner thanks I fixed that anything else ?

Comment: Whoa,..Whoa I am getting negative attacks, I would like to know why? BTW I have changed the question from day-names to words.

Comment: @MukulKumar One big reason for the big negative votes is that the question was very trivial in between a whole bunch of other low-quality questions. When people see enough low-quality questions, they automatically downvote other questions which could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge 98, 6 bytes

```
~~~,,,
```

Any other statements would be *meaningless and useless*. I could possibly do this though (**18 bytes**):

```
3^,<
 @
 w~^
 0
 :
```

But everything but the `,` and the `~` are *meaningless and useless* because it could be done so much simpler.

Comment: DUDE, This is **`Code-Bowling`** means you have to write longest code and not some **`Code-Trolling`** or **`Code-Golf`**

Comment: @MukulKumar This was the longest I could write :-)

Comment: I have changed the question again please read the question again